# How to use abstract model as a ForeignKey in Django?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-models

***I have a model like this:***

```
class A(models.Model):
     ....
     ....
     class Meta:
        abstract = True

class B(A):
     blah..
     blah..

class C(A):
     blah..
     blah..
```

Just I want to use Model `A` as a ForeignKey in different model
like this:-

```
class X(models.Model):
       """
       I want to use like this, But i'm getting error
       """
       name = models.ForeignKey(A)
```

***But I'm getting Error:***

> apis.X.name: (fields.E300) Field defines a relation with model 'A',
>   which is either not installed, or is abstract.

Am I doing something wrong?
How can to avoid this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found the solution:

```
name = models.ForeignKey(A, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, related_name="content_%(class)s")
```

Comment: Did you use `Abstract= True` in your model class?

Comment: Yeah in my base model, not in `X` model

Comment: @MrSingh can you please checkon my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65343715/models-e006-in-abstract-parent-model-django-3-1)?

Answer (score 4):

Setting `Abstract=True` in your Meta means that no table is created in your database.

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes):

> Abstract base classes are useful when you want to put some common
>   information into a number of other models. You write your base class
>   and put abstract=True in the Meta class. This model will then not be
>   used to create any database table. Instead, when it is used as a base
>   class for other models, its fields will be added to those of the child
>   class.

To resolve your issue, you should Foreign key to either model B or model C since those will represent actual tables in your database. Your abstract model should only be used for inheritance purposes.

Comment: Great, Just  i want to try to avoid:
name1 = models.ForeignKey(B),
name2 = models.ForeignKey(C),
How can i avoid this?

Comment: @JustChill Well that is more of a database design question. Depending on what the actual content is that you are working with, there might be cleaner ways.

Comment: I found the solution, Thanks for your answer,

Answer (score 4):

Django provides a special field type (GenericForeignKey) which works around this and allows the relationship to be with any model be it a Abstract one.

Refer to  [GenericForeignKey Docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/contenttypes/#django.contrib.contenttypes.generic.GenericForeignKey) for more insight on this.

```
from django.contrib.contenttypes.fields import GenericForeignKey
from django.contrib.contenttypes.models import ContentType
from django.db import models

class TaggedItem(models.Model):
    tag = models.SlugField()
    content_type = models.ForeignKey(ContentType, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    object_id = models.PositiveIntegerField()
    content_object = GenericForeignKey('content_type', 'object_id')

def __str__(self):
    return self.tag
```

**OR:**

You can make implement a custom model into a base model by using `abstract = True` in it and in your child models you can use it as **ForeignKey**.

**Implementation would be something like this:**

```
class X(models.Model):
   """
   I want to use like this, But i'm getting error
   """
   name = models.ForeignKey(A)
   class Meta:                                                             
       abstract = True                                                     
return A
```

For this one goto to [abstract-base-classes Docs:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes)

Comment: I found the solution,Thanks for your answer