# models.E006 in abstract parent model - Django 3.1

Tags: python-3.x, django, inheritance, django-models

I have an abstract model and a few other classes that inherit from it.

```
# models.py
class Parameter(models.Model):

    data = integer = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
    
    class Meta:
        abstract = True

class Temperature(Parameter):
    
    received_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)

class Ph(Parameter):
    
    received_timestamp = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
```

although my `Parameter` class is abstract, I get `models.E006` error in `python manage.py makemigrations` script.

> graphs.Temperature.data: (models.E006) The field 'data' clashes with the field 'data' from model 'graphs.temperature'.
>
> graphs.Ph.data: (models.E006) The field 'data' clashes with the field 'data' from model 'graphs.ph'.

based on [Abstract base classes](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/db/models/#abstract-base-classes) and this [question](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/28110), if I inherit from an abstract base class, there should be no conflict in the name of the fields of various child classes with their parent (because it's abstract).

any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is unrelated to the abstract base class.

The problem is the `= integer` when you define the `IntegerField`, which means the field is created twice.

Change:

```
data = integer = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)`
```

to

```
data = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: the result of working more than 8-9 hours a day